# Using Jackson, how can you get a list of objects from an interesting json?

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jackson-databind

I have this json, I need to get a list of currency objects using Jackson (the objects itself has a currency name field - "USD", "type" and "show") as a result. How can I do it in a simple and clear way?

Any help would be welcome

```
{
    ...
    "result": "OK",
    "currency": {
        "currencies": {
            "LB": {
                "type": "A",
                "setting": {
                    "show": true,
                },
                "access" : true
            },
            "USD": {
                "type": "B",
                "setting": {
                    "show": true,
                },
                "access" : true
            },
            "RUB": {
                "type": "A",
                "setting": {
                    "show": true,
                },
                "access" : true
            },
          ....
          // and more.. 
         },
       ...
    }
 }
```

Comment: So what the currency object is supposed to be?

Comment: You mean you would like to have a list like `["LB", "USB", "RUB"]` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to add object saving to the list, but in a rather inconvenient way, it seems to me...

```java
ArrayList<Dto> currencyObjectList = new ArrayList<Dto>();
CurrencyStaticDto obj = null;

JsonNode currencies = mapper.readTree(response.getBody()).get("currencies");
Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonNode>> fields = currencies.fields();

while(fields.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry<String, JsonNode> field = fields.next();
    String fieldName = field.getKey();
    JsonNode fieldValue = field.getValue();
    obj = mapper.readValue(fieldValue.toString(),CurrencyStaticDto.class);
    obj.setCurrency(fieldName);

    currencyObjectList.add(obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can read your Json as a Map<String, Object>. Once you have the map you iterate through your map and build your List.
If you want to de-serialize (read) from Json to List of your custom objects you need to have your Json restructured to be Json List and not Json Object. Then you can read your Json into a List directly. 
In any case, there is an Open source Library that has a feature based on Jackson library really simplifies reading/writing objects from/to Json. If you have a json string all you have to do is:

```
Map<String, Object> map = JsonUtils.readObjectFromJsonString(jsonString, Map.class);
```

It throws IOException though, so you will need to handle it. Here is the [Javadoc](http://michaelgantman.github.io/Mgnt/docs/com/mgnt/utils/JsonUtils.html). The library is called MgntUtils and could be found as [Maven artifact](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.github.michaelgantman/MgntUtils) and on the [Github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt/releases) (including javadoc and source code)

Answer (score 0):

```
"currencies": {
        "LB": {
            "type": "A",
            "setting": {
                "show": true,
            },
            "access" : true
        },
        "USD": {
            "type": "B",
            "setting": {
                "show": true,
            },
            "access" : true
        },
        "RUB": {
            "type": "A",
            "setting": {
                "show": true,
            },
            "access" : true
        },
      ....
      // and more.. 
     },
   ...
```

This looks like an Map, not a List. Does that help you? So you would need to create `Currency` class and have jackson parse this structure to Map<String, Currency>. Note that currency will not contain the identifier (like "USD"), only they key in the map will.

Comment: About the list, I mean that as a result we need a list of currency objects, but how to create it with this json example mylist {obj1,obj2,obj3..},and the object itself has the fields-value "currency"(example usd), "type"{A}, and "show"{true/false}

Comment: Please edit your question. It is not clear at all what you need.